# Why is find so much faster than os.walk on large NFS? How to improve traversal speeds on NFS

Tags: python, filesystems, nfs, stat, du

Before I start, I don't have a lot of knowledge in terms of file system behaviors, and so any explanations/hypothesis will greatly help.

## Premise

I have ~3 million files I wanted to find spread across a giant NFS file system. The file system itself has probably ~50-100 million files. The 3 million files are listed by their parent directories.

1. I tried running `find` to find all the necessary files, and it was MUCH faster than `os.walk`, or `os.scandir`, taking at least 4-5x less time. I needed `find` to find symlinks.
2. I tried calling `du`, to find the size of the directories recursively. This took forever - a single call on a big directory took me more than 5 minutes. In comparison to a ext4fs, which took maybe a couple seconds at most, this was much worse.
3. I tried to find mtimes and ctimes using `os.stat`, and this took the longest - to find all 3 million files it takes me ~40 minutes.

The file system is organized in such a way that file sizes are not by themselves huge (low variance), but the number of files under a directory greatly varies.

## Question

1. I know that `find` uses `fts` underneath, but why does it run so much faster?
2. Is there a faster alternative to using `os.stat` or `os.scandir` in python for the same purpose(finding mtimes/ctimes)?

Comment: I suspect your os.scandir call is unnecessarily calling stat() on many files. I have observed this on my end for NFS v3. You can check if this is the case for you by using strace to compare the number of stat() calls with find vs os.scandir.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you give us no [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have to guess quite a bit.

You state that you are searching for symbolic links so I *assume* that you are doing something like `find -type l`.

Using `strace` it was simple to find out that all this does is `stat(2)`, `open(2)`, and `getdents(2)`.  In principle, Python's `os.scandir()` should do the same (and nothing more) because that is why it was introduced.  My tests using `strace` on a Python script also confirmed that.

The reason why it is slower than `find` probably lies in the fact that it creates a Python object for each directory entry it finds.  This means memory management etc.

You could work around this by directly calling the system calls using sth like [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html).  But that's a bit out of scope here.